# How to Erase/remove particular portion of QGraphicPathItem?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am adding QgraphicsPathItem to scene and want to erase particular portion of the Qgraphicspathitem. I am using QgraphicsrectItem as Eraser here.Both the items are colliding, but the QgraphicsPathItem is not getting erased.It remains the same in the scene.I am subtracting the two paths and adding it to the QGraphicspathItem

```
class GraphicsSceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)

        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))
        self.setSceneRect(0,0,1000,1000)
        self.horizontal=QHBoxLayout()
        self.widget=QWidget()
        self.drawrect=False
        self.gridOn = 0
        self.selectionMode = 1
        self.targetForLine = QRect()
        self.drawEnd = True
        self.resizemode=0
        self.eraser_item = None
        self.erasing=False
        self.rect=QGraphicsRectItem()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        try:
            sampleTransform = QTransform()
            self.objectAtMouse = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), sampleTransform)
            if self.selectionMode == 2:
                if self.drawEnd == True:
                    self.drawEnd = False
                elif self.drawEnd == False:
                    self.drawEnd = True
                    self.drawLineObj = None
            if self.drawEnd == False:
                self.lineInsertPoint = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")
                tempPainterPath = QPainterPath()
                self.drawLineObj = QGraphicsPathItem()
                self.drawLineObj.setPos(self.lineInsertPoint.x(), self.lineInsertPoint.y())
                self.drawLineObj.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
                self.drawLineObj.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt.gray)))
                self.drawLineObj.setPath(tempPainterPath)
                self.addItem(self.drawLineObj)
                self.drawLineObj.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            if event.buttons() == Qt.RightButton and self.resizemode == 1:
                self.erasing = True
                self.rect.setRect(event.scenePos().x()-5, event.scenePos().y()-5, 10, 10)
                print(event.pos().x(),event.pos().y())
                self.addItem(self.rect)
                self.rect.setPen(QColor(Qt.red))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in mousepress",e)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        try:
            if self.selectionMode == 2 and self.drawEnd == False and self.erasing == False:
                f1 = QPainterPath()
                gridPos = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")
                f1.moveTo(0, 0)
                f1.lineTo(0, 6)
                f1.lineTo((gridPos.x() - self.lineInsertPoint.x()), 6)
                f1.lineTo((gridPos.x() - self.lineInsertPoint.x()), 0)
                f1.closeSubpath()
                self.drawLineObj.setPath(f1)
                self.drawLineObj.setPos(self.lineInsertPoint.x(), self.lineInsertPoint.y() + 5)
                self.drawLineObj.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt.gray)))
                pen = QPen(QColor(Qt.gray))
                pen.setWidth(0)
                self.drawLineObj.setPen(pen)
                self.drawLineObj._property = []
                self.drawLineObj._angle = 0
            if self.selectionMode == 2 and self.drawEnd == True:
                self.targetForLine = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForRect")
                self.update()
            if event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton and self.erasing:
                print(event.scenePos().x(),event.scenePos().y())

                self.rect.setRect(event.scenePos().x() - 5, event.scenePos().y() - 5,
                                         10, 10)

                for item in self.collidingItems(self.rect):
                    new = item.path()-(self.rect.shape())
                    item.setPath(new)
                    print('collided')

            else:
                self.targetForLine = QRect()

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in mousemove",e)
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.drawrect==True or self.tLext==2 or self.tRext==2 or self.BLext==2 or self.BRext==2:
            self.drawrect=False
            self.tLext=0
            self.tRext=0
            self.BLext=0
            self.BRext=0
            QApplication.changeOverrideCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            mainWindow.pointer.setChecked(False)
            if self.rect != None:
                self.removeItem(self.rect)

    def TargPosForLine(self, position, mode):
        try:
            clicked_column = int((position.y() // 16)) * 16
            clicked_row = int((position.x() // 16)) * 16
            if clicked_column < 0:
                clicked_column = 0
            if clicked_row < 0:
                clicked_row = 0
            if (mode == "ForRect"):
                return QRect(clicked_row, clicked_column, 16, 16)
            elif (mode == "ForLine"):
                return QPointF(clicked_row, clicked_column)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in TargPosForLine", e)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = GraphicsSceneClass()
        self.view=QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
        self.linePointerButton = QToolButton()
        self.linePointerButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.linePointerButton.setText("Drawline")
        self.linePointerButton.setToolTip("Draw Track")
        self.linePointerButton.clicked.connect(self.setPointerMode)
        self.resizebutton = QToolButton()
        self.resizebutton.setText("Resize")
        self.resizebutton.setCheckable(True)
        self.resizebutton.clicked.connect(self.resizepath)
   
        self.widg=QWidget()
        self.horizontal=QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.view)
        self.widg.setLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widg)
        self.tool=self.addToolBar("Tool")
        self.tool.addWidget(self.linePointerButton)
        self.tool.addWidget(self.resizebutton)
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        try:
            key = event.key()
            if key == Qt.Key_Escape:
                but = self.linePointerButton
                self.scene.selectionMode = 1
                but.setChecked(True)
        except Exception:
            print("Keypress is not working")
    def setPointerMode(self):
        try:
            self.scene.selectionMode =2

        except Exception:
            print("Not able to change the selectionmode")
    def resizepath(self):
        self.scene.resizemode=1
        self.scene.selectionMode = 1
        self.linePointerButton.setChecked(False)
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path and the `item` and the shape from `self.rect` don't share the same coordinates system. So, when you want to remove the eraser from the line, the `rect`, you have to use a common coordinates system (for example, the one of you scene):

```
for item in self.collidingItems(self.rect):
                    new = item.mapToScene(item.path())-self.rect.mapToScene(self.rect.shape()) # translate the paths to the scene coords system
                    item.setPath(item.mapFromScene(new)) # translate the path from the scene coords system
```